Move nested Ansible dictionary enriching item with first level index?
TL;DR: I need to flatten an Ansible dictionary of dictionaries so that sub items are moved at the root level and their original parent key added to them.
Context: I need to populate a TOML file using Ansible with configuration options coming from an Ansible variable/fact. I am using community.general.ini_file to populate the .toml file because it works fine (in my case).
My input variable/fact is simple:
config:
  param0_1: value0_1 # This key-value pair has no section/table
  section1: # This dict contains all the key-value pairs for section/table "section1"
    param1_1: value1_1
  section2: # Section/table "section2"
    param2_1: value2_1
    param2_2: value2_2

And I want the final TOML file to looks like this (= have those settings):
param0_1 = 'value0_1'

[section1]
param1_1 = 'value1_1'

[section2]
param2_1 = 'value2_1'
param2_2 = 'value2_2'

I managed to obtain what I want using this Server Fault "Using Ansible ini_file with nested dict?" answer which uses Jinja and JSON notation to process/transform the input in the desired output.
Here is a playbook with such solution:
# Usage: ansible-playbook playbook.yml -C -D
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    config:
      param0_1: value0_1
      section1:
        param1_1: value1_1
      section2:
        param2_1: value2_1
        param2_2: value2_2
    config_flat_via_jinja_json: >-
      [
        {% for section, subdict in config.items() %}
          {% if subdict is mapping %}
            {% for key, value in subdict.items() %}
              {
                "section": "{{ section }}",
                "key": "{{ key }}",
                "value": "{{ value }}"
              }
              {% if not loop.last %}
                ,
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            {
              "section": null,
              "key": "{{ section }}",
              "value": "{{ subdict }}"
            }
          {% endif %}
          {% if not loop.last %}
            ,
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      ]

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      config:
        param0_1: value0_1
        section1:
          param1_1: value1_1
        section2:
          param2_1: value2_1
          param2_2: value2_2
  - set_fact:
      config_flat_via_jinja_json: >-
        [
          {% for section, subdict in config.items() %}
            {% if subdict is mapping %}
              {% for key, value in subdict.items() %}
                {
                  "section": "{{ section }}",
                  "key": "{{ key }}",
                  "value": "{{ value }}"
                }
                {% if not loop.last %}
                  ,
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
              {
                "section": null,
                "key": "{{ section }}",
                "value": "{{ subdict }}"
              }
            {% endif %}
            {% if not loop.last %}
              ,
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        ]
  - debug:
      var: config
  - debug:
      var: config_flat_via_jinja_json

  - name: loop on config_flat_via_jinja_json | list
    debug:
      var: item
    loop: "{{ config_flat_via_jinja_json | list }}"

  - name: Configure application
    # Using ini_file module to populates the TOML file. It works for our need, ini sections are like TOML tables.
    ini_file:
      path: config.toml
      section: '{{ item.section }}'
      option: '{{ item.key }}'
      value: '{{ item.value }}'
      # Will remove configuration line from config file if config value is empty
      state: '{{ "present" if item.value != "" else "absent" }}'
    loop: "{{ config_flat_via_jinja_json | list }}"

Which has the following output for "config_flat_via_jinja_json":
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "config_flat_via_jinja_json": [
        {
            "key": "param0_1",
            "section": null,
            "value": "value0_1"
        },
        {
            "key": "param1_1",
            "section": "section1",
            "value": "value1_1"
        },
        {
            "key": "param2_1",
            "section": "section2",
            "value": "value2_1"
        },
        {
            "key": "param2_2",
            "section": "section2",
            "value": "value2_2"
        }
    ]
}

I works but it looks like an hack for something I think is doable in native Ansible.
Is it?
Note 1: Because the TOML file gets altered from outside of Ansible I cannot use an Ansible template here. Beside I think it's irrelevant to the main issue I'm struggling with.
Note 2: I am using Ansible v2.10 (let's hope such "old" version is not a disqualifier for solutions).

We can simplify the logic required to transform the config dictionary into a more useful data structure. Our goal here is to go from a single dictionary into a list of dictionaries formatted such that we can use it with the subelements filter.
Here's one possible solution:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    config:
      param0_1: value0_1
      section1:
        param1_1: value1_1
      section2:
        param2_1: value2_1
        param2_2: value2_2
  tasks:
  - loop: "{{ config.keys() }}"
    vars:
      _config: []
    set_fact:
        _config: >-
          {% if config[item] is mapping -%}
          {{ _config + [{'name': item, 'items': config[item]|dict2items}] }}
          {% else -%}
          {{ _config + [{'name': 'default', 'items': {item: config[item]} | dict2items}] }}
          {% endif -%}

  - debug:
      var: _config

  - name: Configure application
    ini_file:
      path: config.toml
      section: '{{ (item.0.name == "default") | ternary("", item.0.name) }}'
      option: '{{ item.1.key }}'
      value: '{{ item.1.value }}'
      state: '{{ "present" if item.1.value != "" else "absent" }}'
    loop: "{{ _config | subelements('items') }}"

The set_fact task produces a data structure that looks like this:
[
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "param0_1",
        "value": "value0_1"
      }
    ],
    "name": "default"
  },
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "param1_1",
        "value": "value1_1"
      }
    ],
    "name": "section1"
  },
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "param2_1",
        "value": "value2_1"
      },
      {
        "key": "param2_2",
        "value": "value2_2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "section2"
  }
]

Running the above playbook produces a config.toml that looks like:
param0_1 = value0_1

[section1]
param1_1 = value1_1
[section2]
param2_1 = value2_1
param2_2 = value2_2

I have tested this with Ansible 2.10 on Python 3.10 and it seems to work:
ansible-playbook 2.10.17
  config file = /src/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.14 (main, Sep  4 2024, 06:02:46) [GCC 12.2.0]


subelements filter is convenient. We went with this solution, and pair review moved param0_1 under it's own dict, named ~ (considered as null in YAML) so the set_fact was simplified to only deal with config[item] being a mapping.

Q: "... something I think is doable in native Ansible."
A: There are many options:
Module community.general.ini_file
For example, given the file for testing
shell> cat /tmp/config.toml
param0_8 = value0_8
param0_9 = value0_9

[section2]
param2_1 = value2_x
param2_2 = value2_2

[section3]
param3_1 = value3_1
param3_2 = value3_2

Create the lists
  defaults: "{{ config | dict2items | rejectattr('value', 'mapping') }}"
  sections: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for sec in  config | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'mapping') %}
    {% for opt,val in sec.value.items() %}
    - {section: {{ sec.key }}, key: {{ opt }}, value: {{ val }} }
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}

gives
  defaults:
    - {key: param0_1, value: value0_1}

  sections:
    - {key: param1_1, section: section1, value: value1_1}
    - {key: param2_1, section: section2, value: value2_1}
    - {key: param2_2, section: section2, value: value2_2}

Update the file
    - ini_file:
        path: /tmp/config.toml
        section: "{{ (item.section | d(omit)) }}"
        option: "{{ item.key }}"
        value: "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ defaults + sections }}"

gives
shell> cat /tmp/config.toml
param0_8 = value0_8
param0_9 = value0_9
param0_1 = value0_1

[section2]
param2_1 = value2_1
param2_2 = value2_2

[section3]
param3_1 = value3_1
param3_2 = value3_2
[section1]
param1_1 = value1_1



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    config:
      param0_1: value0_1
      section1:
        param1_1: value1_1
      section2:
        param2_1: value2_1
        param2_2: value2_2

    defaults: "{{ config | dict2items | rejectattr('value', 'mapping') }}"
    sections: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for sec in  config | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'mapping') %}
      {% for opt,val in sec.value.items() %}
      - {section: {{ sec.key }}, key: {{ opt }}, value: {{ val }} }
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: defaults | to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: sections | to_yaml

    - ini_file:
        path: /tmp/config.toml
        section: "{{ (item.section | d(omit)) }}"
        option: "{{ item.key }}"
        value: "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ defaults + sections }}"



Filter community.general.to_ini
Test it if you want to write a template on your own. See the filter community.general.to_ini. This filter works with sections only. Therefore, you have to separate sections and, let's say, "defaults"
  defaults: "{{ config | dict2items | rejectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"
  sections: "{{ config | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"

gives
  defaults:
    param0_1: value0_1

  sections:
    section1: {param1_1: value1_1}
    section2: {param2_1: value2_1, param2_2: value2_2}

Create the template
  config_flat_via_jinja_json: |
    {% for k,v in defaults.items() %}
    {{ k }} = {{ v }}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ sections | community.general.to_ini }}

gives
param0_1 = value0_1

[section1]
param1_1 = value1_1

[section2]
param2_1 = value2_1
param2_2 = value2_2

Create the file
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/config.toml
        content: |
          {{ config_flat_via_jinja_json }}

gives
shell> cat /tmp/config.toml 
param0_1 = value0_1

[section1]
param1_1 = value1_1

[section2]
param2_1 = value2_1
param2_2 = value2_2



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    config:
      param0_1: value0_1
      section1:
        param1_1: value1_1
      section2:
        param2_1: value2_1
        param2_2: value2_2

    defaults: "{{ config | dict2items | rejectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"
    sections: "{{ config | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"

    config_flat_via_jinja_json: |
      {% for k,v in defaults.items() %}
      {{ k }} = {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}

      {{ sections | community.general.to_ini }}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: defaults

    - debug:
        var: sections | to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ config_flat_via_jinja_json }}

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/config.toml
        content: |
          {{ config_flat_via_jinja_json }}



Q: "Note 1: Because the TOML file gets altered from outside of Ansible I cannot use an Ansible template here ..."
A: You can use a template. Get the current configuration and combine it with your update. For example, given the current file
shell> cat /tmp/config.toml
param0_8 = value0_8
param0_9 = value0_9

[section2]
param2_1 = value2_x
param2_2 = value2_2

[section3]
param3_1 = value3_1
param3_2 = value3_2

Declare the variables
  fetch_dest: /tmp/ansible/fetch
  config_file: /tmp/config.toml
  config_file_orig: "{{ fetch_dest }}/{{inventory_hostname }}{{ config_file }}"
  config_orig: "{{ lookup('file', config_file_orig) | community.general.jc('ini') }}

Fetch the file
    - fetch:
        dest: "{{ fetch_dest }}"
        src: "{{ config_file }}"

gives
  config_orig:
    param0_8: value0_8
    param0_9: value0_9
    section2:
      param2_1: value2_x
      param2_2: value2_2
    section3:
      param3_1: value3_1
      param3_2: value3_2

Then, the drill is straightforward. In addition to the already known variables get the defaults_orig and sections_orig
  defaults_orig: "{{ config_orig | dict2items | rejectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"                    
  sections_orig: "{{ config_orig | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"

and combine the dictionaries in the template
  config_flat_via_jinja_json: |
    {% for k,v in (defaults_orig | combine(defaults)).items() %}
    {{ k }} = {{ v }}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ sections_orig | combine(sections) | community.general.to_ini }}

gives
param0_8 = value0_8
param0_9 = value0_9
param0_1 = value0_1
  
[section2]
param2_1 = value2_1
param2_2 = value2_2
  
[section3]
param3_1 = value3_1
param3_2 = value3_2
  
[section1]
param1_1 = value1_1

Write the file.


Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    fetch_dest: /tmp/ansible/fetch
    config_file: /tmp/config.toml
    config_file_orig: "{{ fetch_dest }}/{{inventory_hostname }}{{ config_file }}"
    config_orig: "{{ lookup('file', config_file_orig) | community.general.jc('ini') }}"

    defaults_orig: "{{ config_orig | dict2items | rejectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"
    sections_orig: "{{ config_orig | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"

    config:
      param0_1: value0_1
      section1:
        param1_1: value1_1
      section2:
        param2_1: value2_1
        param2_2: value2_2

    defaults: "{{ config | dict2items | rejectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"
    sections: "{{ config | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'mapping') | items2dict }}"

    config_flat_via_jinja_json: |
      {% for k,v in (defaults_orig | combine(defaults)).items() %}
      {{ k }} = {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}

      {{ sections_orig | combine(sections) | community.general.to_ini }}

  tasks:

    - fetch:
        dest: "{{ fetch_dest }}"
        src: "{{ config_file }}"

    - debug:
        var: config_orig

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ config_flat_via_jinja_json }}

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ config_file }}"
        content: |
          {{ config_flat_via_jinja_json }}



Q: "I have trouble using community.general.to_ini and community.general.jc (jc package is installed)."
A: If jc is installed use the lookup pipe instead of file
config_orig: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cat ' ~ config_file_orig ~ ' | jc --ini')  }}"

Write the template on your own if community.general.to_ini is missing
    config_flat_via_jinja_json: |
      {% for k,v in (defaults_orig | combine(defaults)).items() %}
      {{ k }} = {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for sec,conf in (sections_orig | combine(sections)).items() %}
      [{{ sec }}]
      {% for k,v in conf.items() %}
      {{ k }} = {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}

      {% endfor %}

As an advantage, you can control the formatting
shell> cat config.toml
param0_8 = value0_8
param0_9 = value0_9
param0_1 = value0_1

[section2]
param2_1 = value2_1
param2_2 = value2_2

[section3]
param3_1 = value3_1
param3_2 = value3_2

[section1]
param1_1 = value1_1


The OP needs to use the ini module because they don't "own" the target file ("Because the TOML file gets altered from outside of Ansible I cannot use an Ansible template here.") -- it may already contain configuration separate from that generated by the playbook. The solution presented here would overwrite the target configuration file.

I added an example of how to update the configuration. Thank you.

Thanks for the solution, nice use of rejectattr/selectattr to separate scalars and dict (hadn't thought of it). I had trouble using community.general.to_ini (too old collection) and community.general.jc (not recognized although jc Debian package is installed) so I could not check if rewriting the configuration file with the combine() to keep existing settings was truly idempotent.

You're welcome. I added a simplified module option.

Optionally, use the lookup pipe and run the jc command on your own. Also, write the template on your own if to_ini is missing.  I added an example.
